# Functional setState doesn't work in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

My attempts to change the value of the state "id" with setState doesn't work.
I've tried using ordinary setState, which doesn't update the value of the state. So I tried a functional setState, but it still doesn't work.
The alert shows 0, instead of 5.

Why is it not updating?

```
class Form extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {lat: null,
                lng: null,
                radius: null,
                id: 0,
                filename: ''};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    function setStateFunction(state, props) {
      const newState = {...state, id: 5};
      return newState;
    }
    this.setState(setStateFunction);

    alert(this.state.id);
  }

  render(){
    return (<div>...</div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a giant anti-pattern over there. First of all, it does not make sense, to be initializing the `state` in `constructor` only to re-initalize it in `componentDidMount`.

So unless `componentDidMount` itself is asynchronous, you should never even be using `setState` inside it (Even the default configuration by the React team actually throws an error in their [eslint-react-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) if you even attempt to do so - which by the way I strongly recommend you install, it's very good for beginners to help prevent common antipatterns or common mistakes).

Not to mention, `state` itself **is asynchronous**, so it does not update the moment you change it. Furthermore I presume you're trying to learn here, but just in case this code goes to actual production, you could always simply declare it in constructor

Essentially your code could simply be

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // rest of your state ...
      id: 5
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.state
    alert(id)
  }
}
```

As to the code itself, as I've mentioned, `setState` is an asynchronous operation, that does update the state instantly.  One important rule to remember, **any time you set state and want to work with the changed value, you should provide a callback**

`setState` is defined the following way `setState(Function => Object | Object, callbackFunction)`

So essentially, what you want to be doing in your code is

```
this.setState(setStateFunction, () => alert(this.state.id))
```

Comment: I made this test pattern because I wanted to get setState to work correctly before using it in my main application. So this is just a test pattern.
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Updating a React component's state is asynchronous. It does not happen immediately.**

Since `setState` is async, the changes might not get reflected as soon as you call it even by passing a function as well. If you want to check whether the value is getting updated or not you can check by using the callback of `setState` result like below.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    function setStateFunction(state, props) {
      const newState = {...state, id: 5};
      return newState;
    }
    this.setState(setStateFunction, () => {
      alert(this.state.id)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Happy to have helped you :)